# Why weren't Puck and Emilia surprised when Subaru called out Emillia's spirit to protect her in episode 3?

Tags: re-zero

Why weren't Puck and Emilia surprised when Subaru called out Emillia's spirit to activate the crystal shield?

[image]

After Subaru returned after his death, he hadn't made any contact with those two, Puck and Emilia, whatsoever. In that situation, how come Emilia never asked about how Subaru knew what her spirit companion's (Puck) name was and for how long it could stay active/on duty.

Comment: no one could answer, so I'll assume this part's story was flawed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is discuss by Emilia and Pack in the after event of the fight with Elsa (Chibi Short 3). Where Emilia ask Pack how come he respond to Subaru call and ask if they knew each other. Pack answer with a no but hearing his name being shouted upon cause him to be quickly summoned to aid Emilia.

Pack also answer that Subaru was sincerely just there to aid her noticing no sign of malevolent and ill intent on Subaru. and if he ever did, Pack will annihilate Subaru himself.

Comment: hmm oh yeah now I see ! thanks for your answer !